# Default IP for a wireless network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, static-ip

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

I'm travelling many times, and many places I know the wireless settings.
Every of the wireless networks are using DHCP.

Only one place where I need a static IP is home. I need 192.168.1.200. IP in this place.

Can I set the network settings (IPV4) to it is use DHCP commonly, but in this network use 192.168.1.200 (static)?
Or can I write some script that automatically set IPV4 to dhcp, and run this on Windows start, but on home I click on other script what set the IP to this static, and DNC to *.1?

Now I set this by hand, but many times I forget it. The router "application port forwards" are binded to this IP...

Comment: Why do you have a static address in your home network? If your router has a dhcp, you can configure it to give you this ip every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open Network Connections in Control Panel and enter the wireless card properties you will be able to configure IPv4 settings (Internet Protocol Properties).

You have a tab in there named `'Alternate configuration'`. On `'General'` tab leave option Obtain automatically. On `'Alternate configuration'` setup your prefered IP address. This will be used in have your host will connect to the network without DHCP - your home network.

If you want a static IP address in your home while using DHCP at the same time - you need to setup IP reservation on your wifi router to give you the same IP address based on your MAC address [Network card (NIC) identificator].